# Behavioural Voltage

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, ltspice, spice, bridge-rectifier

If I directly connect it to the power stages in a midstage model from an output of a rectifier, the rectification seems off. If I add it to the power stage using a Behavioural Voltage, it seems smooth and gives the desired output.

Why is it so?
I have been answered in the question.

But if I want to remove it and connect it directly, what should I do to get the desired output?

PS: The output load is 200Ohms in the later stages of the power circuit with multiple inductances.

[image]

Comment: Can you show more of the circuit? My guess is that you are probably loading the input too much

Comment: Its 90V. Currently dont have the asc file. Sorry.

Comment: Yes the power stage has a buck converter, to a 52ohm output

Comment: Do you know the difference between this model and a simple wire? The difference is that the current on the right side doesn't have to come from the left side. It's an ideal buffer stage.

Comment: How could I use a more real-life version of a buffer stage?

Comment: Because the behavioural model acts as a high impedance load and doesn't drain C4 the way a real load does. Add a resistor equal to your load across C4 to fix the behavioural load version.

Comment: @SubhransuSekharBhattacharya  Your term "the cyclical model comes back" will not be clear to some people. The query above re its meaning is a reasonable one. || Andy's comment is excessively obscure - he is making the point (or trying to) that the system is isolating input and output - just as a window pane does in a wind analogy.

Comment: The BV buffers the fragile Vin. A BV makes its own power (as if using magic) and therefore does not load C4. Not loading C4 means that no current is taken from it and its terminal voltage looks nice and smooth. Loading C4 (if fed from a diode that rectifies AC) means ripple artefacts @SubhransuSekharBhattacharya

Comment: Thanks, people solved it. A simple buffer worked. LT Spice is super weird. Tried the same 5 times before, didn't work.

Comment: The level of petty rudeness by several people doesn't help anyone. I have copied ALL the comments to chat so anyone interested can view them and left the more worthwhile ones here. I "*strongly suggest*" that typical internet rude-speak not be continued. This conversation has been [copied to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115219/discussion-on-question-by-subhransu-sekhar-bhattacharya-behavioural-voltage).

Comment: @SubhransuSekharBhattacharya PLEASE listen to this carefully: You said "

Yes the power stage has a buck converter, to a 52ohm output" , and you also say elsewhere the load is 200 Ohms. And you mention inductances. ...  -> You have not told us what you are trying to model, nor whether energy transfer from the buck converter to the load is an important consideration, nor what the voltage is. And more.
At 5V the power would be about 0.5 Watt into 52 Ohms. At 10V about 2 Watt. A buffer "in the middle"  removes the need for the buck converter to provide most (or all) of this power. ...

Comment: ... Depending on the aim (which you have not specified) a buffer may be a good solution or make complete nonsense of the real world situation. If you do not provide more detail the question approaches being meaningless and any answer has a high risk of being wrong.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yes, I get that, but it's solved. Thank You. There is no specific aim. I am just learning LT Spice, experimenting with things. I have a feeling one is prohibited from asking things that are not PROFESSIONAL enough.

Comment: @SubhransuSekharBhattacharya You are missing my technical point. | You need to have a clear understanding of your aim if you intend to learn accurately from a technical Q&A session. || You say the output is from a BC (buck converter). A buck converter output is almost always used as a source of energy. Maybe a power supply in its own right or powering a driver stage or ... . | IF this is the case then a buffer is **NOT** the correct solution for you!!!  A buffer draws it's power from "magic" - usually a power supply powered from where-ever.  ...

Comment: In a simulation the buffer may make the power to the load smooth or steady or whatever BUT it completely negates using the BC as a power source. || It is far far less common to use a BC output as a signal source in its own right. One MIGHT use a buffer to drive a sensor path for regulation or similar - but you would not usually need a buffer at all for this purpose. | SO it is more likely than not that the understanding you have gained is a false one that will lead you astray subsequently. If you stop at this point you may find the answer you have got is less than helpful subsequently.

Comment: @SubhransuSekharBhattacharya  "Non professional" queries are very probably the majority of what occur here. What is aimed at by people  who try to help is to help newcomers to understand what it takes to address a problem well. My technical points above suggest what may yet be needed to ensure your question and answer match your expectations. They MAY but at present it is more likely than not that they don't.  Several commenters were trying to tell you that. Trying to look past any communications misunderstandings (in both directions) is usually helpful.